# Byte swap of a byte array into a long long

Tags: c++

I have a program where i simply copy a byte array into a long long array. There are a total of 20 bytes and so I just needed a long long of 3. The reason I copied the bytes into a long long was to make it portable on 64bit systems.

I just need to now byte swap before I populate that array such that the values that go into it go reversed.

there is a byteswap.h which has _int64 bswap_64(_int64) function that i think i can use. I was hoping for some help with the usage of that function given my long long array. would i just simply pass in the name of the long long and read it out into another long long array?
I am using c++ not .net or c#

update:
clearly there are issues i am still confused about. for example, workng with byte arrays that just happen to be populated with 160 bit hex string which then has to be outputed in decimal form made me think about the case where if i just do a simple assignment to a long (4 byte) array my worries would be over. Then i found out that this code would ahve to run on a 64bit sun box. Then I thought that since the sizes of data from one env to another can change just a simple assignment would not cut it. this made me think about just using a long long to just make the code sort of immune to that size issue. however, then i read about endianess and how 64bit reads MSB vs 32bit which is LSB. So, taking my data and reversing it such that it is stored in my long long as MSB was the only solution that came to mind. ofc, there is the case about the 4 extra bytes which in this case does not matter and i simply will take the decimal output and display any random six digits i choose. However programatically, i guess it would be better to just work with 4 byte longs and not deal with that whole wasted 4 byte issue.

Comment: Right off the bat one issue you'll need to think about is that 20 bytes won't completely fill a `long long` array with 3 elements (assuming that a `long long` is 8 bytes on your platform).  What do you want done about the left overs?

Comment: Why are you using a long long? What is the purpose of the byteswap, and generally what are you trying to do? If your data is 20 bytes obviously you're not dealing with integer data, so moving it to a long long doesn't seem like a 64-bit compatability issue. Also if your byte swap is for endian reasons you need to know the underlying format of the data in order to do the byte swap correctly.

Comment: All of unknown (yahoo)'s other questions hint that he/she has some misunderstandings about endianness and integer representations.

Comment: please look at my question for info. also, this program although is compiled and unit tested on a 32bit machine the exe will run on a 64 bit box. this is what caused all this confusion for me.

Comment: @unknown, what exactly do you need to output in decimal, the value of *each byte*, or the value of the array *interpreted as a 160-bit integer*?  It sounds like you're dealing with a checksum, which are usually interpreted byte-by-byte because they are so large.

Comment: i need to output ultimately 6 digit decimal output from the 160bit byte array which happens to have hex strings.

Comment: What do you mean "6 digit decimal output"?  2^160 has way more than 6 digits in base-10.  What do you want to do with this data?  Why wouldn't you just keep it as a byte array?  As Nick said, these sorts of things are usually dealt with byte-by-byte.

Comment: this data is used to generate a code..a random number. so, once i have this data in decimal i just pick any six digits i choose to display. since the data in they byte array is a hex string (randomly generated) and my output must be a six digit random number i thought to just convert the string into decimal and then pick 6 digits to display. i could keep it as a byte array and parse through the hex string picking up the first six digits i get as a possibility however if i convert it, it would make it more cryptic than just parsing the hex string or adds entropy to the whole process.

Comment: If your goal is to generate a random number, why are you not just using a random number generator like rand() (see http://members.cox.net/srice1/random/crandom.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between this and your previous questions, it sounds like there are several fundamental confusions here:

1. If your program is going to be run on a 64-bit machine, it sounds like you should compile and unit-test it on a 64-bit machine.  Running unit tests on a 32-bit machine can give you confidence the program is correct in that environment, but doesn't necessarily mean the code is correct for a 64-bit environment.
2. You seem to be confused about how 32- and 64-bit architectures relate to endianness.  32-bit machines are not always little-endian, and 64-bit machines are not always big-endian.  They are two separate concepts and can vary independently.
3. Endianness only matters for single values consisting of multiple bytes; for example, the integer 305,419,896 (0x12345678) requires 4 bytes to represent, or a UTF-16 character  (usually) requires 2 bytes to represent.  For these, the order of storage matters because the bytes are interpreted as a single unit.  It sounds like what you are working with is a sequence of raw bytes (like a checksum or hash).  Values like this, where multiple bytes are not interpreted in groups, are not affected by the endianness of the processor.  In your case, casting the byte array to a `long long *` actually *creates* a potential endianness problem (on a little-endian architecture, your bytes will now be interpreted in the opposite order), not the other way around.
4. Endianness also doesn't matter unless the little-endian and big-endian versions of your program actually have to *communicate* with each other.  For example, if the little-endian program writes a file containing multi-byte integers without swapping and the big-endian program reads it in, the big-endian program will probably misinterpret the data.  It sounds like you think your code that works on a little-endian platform will suddenly break on a big-endian platform even if the two never exchange data.  You generally don't need to be worried about the endianness of the architecture if the two versions don't need to talk to each other.
5. Another point of confusion (perhaps a bit pedantic).  A byte does not store a "hex value" versus a "decimal value," it stores an integer.  Decimal and hexadecimal are just two different ways of representing (printing) a particular integer value.  It's all binary in the computer's memory anyway, hexadecimal is just an easy conversion to and from binary and decimal is convenient to our brains since we have ten fingers.

Assuming what you're trying to do is print the value of each byte of the array as decimal, you could do this:

```
unsigned char bytes[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bytes) / sizeof(unsigned char); ++i)
{
  printf("%u ", (unsigned int)bytes[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Output should be something like:

> 18 52 86 120

Comment: and yes you are correct i am dealing with a hash. and omg you nailed my confusion on the head. I thought that since i am on a 32bit i would automatically have to deal with endianess since i was treating my data of raw bytes (which happen to be hex string) as actual hex data values which clearly was not the case. so, then the question is won't it matter how the raw bytes are read? on a 32bit system they will read the raw byte hex string one way and on a 64bit system another way? lastly, how do i make my hex string into decimal if by saving it in a byte of say int or long will cause endianess?

Comment: @unknown, edited.  Still not exactly sure what formatting you want, perhaps this is it?

Comment: ok, so the byte array contains a hex string as in "1abc54fd928b". this is the 160bit string that i need to change to decimals such that i can then pick any six digits out of it. I don't have to convert this into a decimal instead i could just parse through that string and pick all the numbers and just display the first six i get. however, i thought it might be better to just convert the hex string to decimal and then pick the first 6.

Comment: @unknown, I'm still having a very hard time understanding exactly what it is you want.  Do you want to print any six of the *hexadecimal digits* as decimal?  Perhaps you should open a new question and state your original problem as straightforwardly as possible (perhaps with example input and output) instead of getting bogged down in details of the solution.

Comment: but if i store any information from the byte array into any other sort of data type will this automatically mean that i am adding endianness then? also, when dealing with raw bytes how the are actually read on one system vs another makes a difference since i need for the ouputs in this case to match. so even if i keep it a byte array and go through it. does this mean if someone run my prog on say a sun station 64bit vs a linx box using 32 bit they both will get diff results since they are reading the byte array differently? MSB vs LSB? or does that never come into play here.

Comment: Ahh, or maybe you're asking to filter out all the A-F digits and print only the digits in the number from 0-9?

Comment: MSB vs LSB will not come into play as long as you are interpreting the byte array only one byte at a time.

Comment: first off you are right that the digits have to be numerical from the hex string. however by converting the hex string to say decimals and then picking the digits adds a bit more randomness to the final output. i hope this really helps clear things up as to what i am looking to do. BTW, reading bytes MSB vs LSB won't that make a diff? say my hex string in byte array is a1234 would the 32bit processor "generally" if it is LE read it 4321a vs a sun box on 64bit BE as a1234?

Comment: umm scratch that second question i think a byte on each machine would be the same...and my example is more than that. eeek i think i get that part. so, would it still be feasable to do a conversion from hex string to decimal and still avoid complications?

Comment: Please read point #5.  Your data is binary - not hexadecimal or decimal.  It does not make sense to talk about "converting" your data from one to the other.  You can only print it as one to the other.

Comment: If you want six decimal digits, start at the first byte.  Print it in decimal.  Count how many digits that involved and subtract from six.  That's how many you still have left to print.  Move to the next byte.  Print it in decimal.  Repeat until you've printed six digits.  However, if all you need is a random integer, you should really look into a pseudo-random number generator.

Answer (score 1):

Ithink you should look at: htonl() and family

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html

This family of functions is used to encode/decode integers for transport between machines that have different sizes/endianness of integers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write your program in the clearest, simplest way. You shouldn't need to do anything to make it "portable."
2. Byte-swapping is done to translate data of one [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) to another. `bswap_64` is for resolving incompatibility between different 64-bit systems such as Power and X86-64. It isn't for manipulating your data.
3. If you want to reverse bytes in C++, try searching the STL for "reverse." You will find `std::reverse`, a function which takes pointers or iterators to the first and one-past-last bytes of your 20-byte sequence and reverses it. It's in the `<algorithm>` header.