# help with byte array

Tags: c++

I have one byte array which has some raw data like 1aa23486b2..and so on.
I want to represent each byte in the array as a decimal number. I then have to go through the decimal numbers and pick out the first x decimal to output to screen.

if i use int byte [same size as input byte array] would that work? just declare and initialized it
memset(byte,0,same size as input byte array];

then just loop through and copy it over which could do the trick but then how do i choose x amount of digits?

Comment: This seems an awful lot like like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061154/byte-swap-of-a-byte-array-into-a-long-long

Comment: oh wow. we have an assignment about this. that looks similar.

Comment: @djones2010: You (and unknown (yahoo), if you're really not the same person) need to stop asking vague (and completely nonsensical) questions like these, tell us specifically what you're trying to do, preferably with a sample input and *exactly* what kind of output you want.

Comment: Is this homework?  If it is, it's appreciated if you add the "homework" tag so that we know.  I'll add it, and if it isn't homework then I'll take it off.

Comment: If this is indeed homework, it'd be nice if they posted the actual assignment or something.  At least then it'd be clearer what they're trying to do.

Comment: (foundations of c++ class assignment) basically once we have our byte array populated with hash values we then have to take that and print it as decimal values but in my case the length cannot exceed 10 digits.

Comment: The assignment wants us to basically take in a 10 digit hexadecimal value. We then suppose to create a hash of that value and use some api that the teacher gave us. this api takes the hash of that initial input value and then generates a 160bit hash on top of that whose output is put in a byte array initialized as memset(hashoutput,0x00,somesize);

now I am at the last part of the assignment which is to basically take that hashed output which is in a byte array and generate a 10 digit decimal number.

Comment: That last part about producing a 10 digit decimal number from the hash isn't well defined.  What relationship are the two supposed to have?  As written, I could make a function that always generates "1234567890" from *any* input, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: well seems like he just wants us to always produce a 10 digit decimal number from the actual hex bytes. He also states that we in displaying the first 10 digits there could be a case where we might have to truncate and not show the full value of a byte. 

eg. byte array value 0x1b and 0xa2.
if we wanted to display 3 digits it would
1b=27
a2=162

so we would only display 271. That is what it says. 
by the way, since we would be operating on the byte array to display would casting it to an int cause any issues in porting? to say a solaris box?

Comment: If that's really what you want to do, you could use `snprintf` to convert each byte to a string of its decimal representation, concatenate the strings, and take the first 10 characters from the result. (You haven't specified what's supposed to happen if one of the bytes is 0, though.) And why would you think you'd have portability issues?

Answer (score 2):

What about using a printf statement to print the bytes as integers?

```
int numBytes = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", &yourArray[i]);
}

printf("\n");
```

Comment: This, you could do the cast and length selection in the printf formatting.

Comment: well the problem with printf was that when i used it and it returns the number values in the count i came across issues like..
a2 it comes out to 162. this means that if i have another byte like 1b that would be 27. say if i wanted to print 6 and the next byte was 68 the decimal value of that hex would be 104. and i would end up only printing 16227 because 104 is more than 6 digits. see the issue?

Comment: OK, I'm confused.  You have the string "1aa23486b2" in your question.  What is the output you want for this particular string of hex values?